# Is lookup field supported in Salesforce1?

Tags: visualforce, salesforce1-app, lookup

I am new to Salesfore1 & mobile development and facing one issue..

I am trying to create one publisher action with custom VF page as content source. Within my VF Page there was a custom field (i.e. lookup to Account) and it was coming as a text field (no search icon or alternative where to search appropriate account).

[image: Account Lookup field with search icon]

So there is no way for user to search & select account record on custom VF page.
if I keep "SandardStylesheets" property of  tag as TRUE then I can see lookup icon (as we get in web) but having few issue which is discussed [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/28398/lookup-fields-using-salesforce1-and-visualforce).

So my questions are :

1. Is reference field is support in Publsher Action's VF page?
2. If not, is there any quick/easy alternative option?
3. Is it known issue/limitation in Salesforce?
4. Is there any idea posted on the same (tried but unable to find)?

I also found something related in "Salesforce Touch" [**FAQ**](http://www.salesforce.com/docs/en/mobile/touch/mobile-browser-app_on_tablet/touch_faq_tablet_dataentry.htm#touch_faq_tablet_dataentry_LookupFields) :

> As in the full site, lookup fields allow you to associate other records with the one you're creating or editing. But the lookup interface in Salesforce Touch is optimized for working on touchscreen devices.

But the same is not working in Salesforce1.. :(

Please guide..

Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

It is a known limitation of Salesforce1 Mobile and is documented in the Salesforce1 App Developer's Guide.

From the Salesforce1 App Developer's Guide section, [Visualforce Components to Avoid in Salesforce1](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce1.meta/salesforce1/vf_dev_best_practices_components_to_avoid.htm):

> Using <apex:inputField> is fine for fields that display as a basic input field, like text, email, and phone numbers, but avoid using it for field types that use an input widget, such as date and lookup fields.

And, from the [Unsupported Visualforce Components](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce1.meta/salesforce1/vf_dev_best_practices_components_unsupported.htm) section:

> <apex:inputField> for field types that use a widget for input, instead of a basic form field

Additionally, a web developer from Salesforce.com answered the question you referenced ([Lookup fields using Salesforce1 and Visualforce](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/28915/154)) with an answer that stated they weren't supported in that way, so it's a safe bet that's the case. ;)

I did not see any Ideas, either, when I searched for 'Salesforce1': https://success.salesforce.com/ideaSearch?keywords=salesforce1.

I'm not aware of a quick/easy way. Depending on your situation you could try an autocomplete, e.g., [jQuery Mobile - Remote autocomplete](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.1/listview-autocomplete-remote/).

Comment: Does the autocomplete work in Salesforce1? I'm looking to implement something like this for a Publisher Action.

Comment: @ZacheryTapp - I haven't implemented it in a SF1 page, but there's no reason that a JavaScript autocomplete solution shouldn't work.