# Salesforce1 - Lookup Account or Contact on VF Page

Tags: visualforce, salesforce1-app, salesforce1-platform

I am trying to build a Visualforce page for Salesforce1 and I need to be able to look up a Contact or an Account by name. I am wanting to use the same lookup that Salesforce1 uses normally when doing this for creating a Contact or creating an Account

When editing a Contact from the one.app on desktop:

[image]

If you click within the Account Name field that is highlighted above, Salesforce1 will bring you to this mobile-friendly page for searching an Account by name:
[image]

I want to replicate this on my own visualforce page. Thus far I have been trying to use inputField but I have learned that this is highly frowned upon and all it ends up doing is opening up a browser window like it does in Salesforce on desktop.

I have already looked at the following links: 
[Salesforce1 - How to Enable the Standard Lookup Field Search on a Mobile VF Page](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/21846/salesforce1-how-to-enable-the-standard-lookup-field-search-on-a-mobile-vf-page) 
[Lookup fields using Salesforce1 and Visualforce](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/28398/lookup-fields-using-salesforce1-and-visualforce)

However they are lacking the answer to my question, which is how can I replicate this search and clear functionality on a VF page like it is done in the pictures above